# Cannot get length of an Array and map() doesn't work for this array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I defined an array like below:

```
const photos = [];
```

Then added two items to it like below:

```
docs.forEach(item =>
      photos.push({name: item.data().name, url: item.data().url})));
```

When doing console.log(photos), I can see it contains two items:

```
[]
0: {name: "electronics.jpg", url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/freebi…=media&token=c670308a-91b3-4125-ae93-abb2d6409ae2"}
1: {name: "clothing.jpg", url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/freebi…=media&token=b757702e-6a82-4459-beae-11de53830fae"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But when I tried to get the photos.length, it returns 0.

Also, when I tried to iterate through the photos array via map() function, I cannot see the item gets iterated. Code is like below:

```
photos.map(photo => (
                <Image src={photo.url} />
)
```

Can someone kindly let me know where could possibly went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It seems fine, strange problem you've got there. Could you share the entire code of the Component?

Comment: Can you show the _rest_ of the code? There's no way for us to tell whether you're doing sensible things and this is a weird bug, or whether you're doing something that React tells you not to do, like directly writing into `this.state` rather than using `setState` or something.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters, there is probably a problem somewhere but it doesn't look like it is in the posted code

Comment: Possibly you have two arrays called `photos` in different scopes. We can't reproduce this without a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks all! There is nothing special in the code wise. I just looked up the firebase database and push those two items in the photos array.

`const photos = [];
firestore.collection('events')
         .doc(match.params.id).collection('photos')
         .get()
         .then(ref => ref.docs.map(item =>
                  photos.push({name: item.data().name, url: item.data().url})));`

Comment: I used forEach() instead of map() in the above.

Comment: Why the console shows [] instead of something like [{...}, {...}] for photos array?

Comment: I'm wondering could it be possible that firebase calls are async, and by the time firebase calls returned, photos array hasn't been pushed any value yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid `forEach` and do it in one statement as

```
const photos = docs.map(item => {name: item.data().name, url: item.data().url})
```

This will at least create `1` photos variable. Try this, log and let us know what you get next

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the console shows [] instead of something like [{...}, {...}] for photos array?

Comment: I found where it went wrong. It just because firebase calls are all async. By the time when I access the array, the firebase call haven't push anything to the array yet. Thanks though!

Comment: Yes, you need to be careful with `async` calls